Calling question_answering gives a Bad Request error from HuggingFace
When I run this script:
from huggingface_hub import InferenceClient

context = "A machine is set up in such a way that it will short circuit if both the black wire and the red wire touch the battery at the same time. The machine will not short circuit if just one of these wires touches the battery. The black wire is designated as the one that is supposed to touch the battery, while the red wire is supposed to remain in some other part of the machine."
question = "One day, the black wire and the red wire both end up touching the battery at the same time. There is a short circuit. Did the black wire cause the short circuit?"
client = InferenceClient(token = "some token")

result = client.question_answering(question = question, 
                                   context = context,
                                   model="distilbert/distilbert-base-uncased")
print(result)

I get this error:
Bad request:
text input must be of type `str` (single example), `List[str]` (batch or single pretokenized example) or `List[List[str]]` (batch of pretokenized examples).

Here's the entire traceback:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\huggingface_hub\utils\_errors.py:286, in hf_raise_for_status(response, endpoint_name)
    285 try:
--> 286     response.raise_for_status()
    287 except HTTPError as e:

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py:1021, in Response.raise_for_status(self)
   1020 if http_error_msg:
-> 1021     raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)

HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://api-inference.huggingface.co/models/distilbert/distilbert-base-uncased

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

BadRequestError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [18], in <cell line: 10>()
      7 question = "One day, the black wire and the red wire both end up touching the battery at the same time. There is a short circuit. Did the black wire cause the short circuit?"
      8 client = InferenceClient(token = token)
---> 10 result = client.question_answering(question = question, 
     11                                    context = context,
     12                                    model="distilbert/distilbert-base-uncased")
     13 print(result)

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\huggingface_hub\inference\_client.py:924, in InferenceClient.question_answering(self, question, context, model)
    893 """
    894 Retrieve the answer to a question from a given text.
    895 
   (...)
    920 ```
    921 """
    923 payload: Dict[str, Any] = {"question": question, "context": context}
--> 924 response = self.post(
    925     json=payload,
    926     model=model,
    927     task="question-answering",
    928 )
    929 return _bytes_to_dict(response)

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\huggingface_hub\inference\_client.py:240, in InferenceClient.post(self, json, data, model, task, stream)
    237         raise InferenceTimeoutError(f"Inference call timed out: {url}") from error  # type: ignore
    239 try:
--> 240     hf_raise_for_status(response)
    241     return response.iter_lines() if stream else response.content
    242 except HTTPError as error:

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\huggingface_hub\utils\_errors.py:329, in hf_raise_for_status(response, endpoint_name)
    325 elif response.status_code == 400:
    326     message = (
    327         f"\n\nBad request for {endpoint_name} endpoint:" if endpoint_name is not None else "\n\nBad request:"
    328     )
--> 329     raise BadRequestError(message, response=response) from e
    331 # Convert `HTTPError` into a `HfHubHTTPError` to display request information
    332 # as well (request id and/or server error message)
    333 raise HfHubHTTPError(str(e), response=response) from e

BadRequestError:  (Request ID: 5visIkYaup2w-rZQ2gD3Z)

Bad request:
text input must be of type `str` (single example), `List[str]` (batch or single pretokenized example) or `List[List[str]]` (batch of pretokenized examples).

